# How to uninstall an android app from command line on the device

Tags: android, command-line, root, uninstallation

I can uninstall an app on the device from my computer using `adb uninstall <package_name>`,
but I'd like to do the same with a script on the actual device.

I've also tried running an `android.intent.action.DELETE` intent using `am` but it prompts the user for confirmation.

Given that the device is rooted, is it possible to run a command on the device to uninstall an  app without requiring user action/confirmation ?

Comment: I think this is only on topic on [android.se] now. Questions about basic installation and uninstallation have been deemed off-topic on StackExchange

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to run some script on the device?
How do you get a command line? or do we have necessarily to install some app like "cancer" Termux?  a sample script would be nice? I think it has to start with 
#! /system/bin/sh

Comment: I needed to uninstall the app silently (without) the action/confirmation dialog, so, on a rooted device, prefixing the `pm uninstall` command with `su -c` [did the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556750/how-to-uninstall-an-android-app-from-command-line-on-the-device?noredirect=1#comment25540140_17556878). I needed to trigger it from inside my Android app, so used something very similar to [noman's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556750/how-to-uninstall-an-android-app-from-command-line-on-the-device?noredirect=1#comment40067501_17556878)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Trying using the [`pm` command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm):

```
pm uninstall <package_name>
```

or

```
pm uninstall -k <package_name>
```

The `-k` flag keeps the data and cache directories after the package is removed.

I haven't tested this myself, but I don't think this should show a warning message.

Comment: Thanks!(+1) That worked. Depending on the situation `su -c pm uninstall [-k] <package_name>` does the trick if the simply calling pm fails.

Comment: @RaghavSood You should not do `rm <path to apk>` thing as it would leave a lot of garbage to system and that crap will still use storage space (for example, cached apk), and is hard to find without knowledge of system (stuff scattered around filesystem). If you know what you are doing, then why not but plain `rm apkfile` won't do any good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. .This one worked for me: String cmd = "su -c pm uninstall " + packageName;Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); ...  !!!

Comment: @Frxstrem How to update the app please give the adb comments sir

Answer (score 18):

To forcefully uninstall the system user apps:

Use:

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 <package_name>
```

Comment: Yes, most of the devices install application for primary user and uninstall command without specifying user fails. That's the reason I mentioned the word forcefully in there.

Answer (score 14):

`adb shell pm uninstall *your.package.name*`

Did the trick for me.

Comment: In my case I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` when using `*` to delineate package name. Worked with double quotes

Answer (score 12):

And if you want to re-install back package removed **for a user** (i.e. `pm uninstall --user 0`), without root:

```
pm install --user 0 $(pm dump <package name> | awk '/path/{ print $2 }')
```

This will locate `.apk` of the uninstalled package: `pm dump <package name>` and search for a line starting with `path:` to obtain path to the `.apk` (*note that `pm path <package>` won't work for an uninstalled app*) and install it using `pm install --user 0` (*note that `pm install` without `--user` argument wont' work*).

This works for any system app, this is a good alternative to `pm disable-user <package>` which still allows you to easily enable app back via Settings.
For example, you could uninstall Play Store (`pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.vending`) and have no way to enable/install any application on default non-rooted device without access to `adb` or `pm`.

Comment: This is a very useful and severely underrated answer.

Comment: How do you get a command line on android 11 device? or do we have necessarily to install some app like Termux? a sample script would be nice? I think it has to start with #! /system/bin/sh then your pm install ... commands...   Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Some Apps can't be uninstalled,so below command gives the error:

```
adb shell pm uninstall package_name
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Try to run disable command instead,

```
adb shell pm disable package_name
Package package_name new state: disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

I had fail on uninstall some system launchers (for example NovaLauncher)
In this case I recommend to use "disable" instead "uninstall":

```
pm disable <package_name>
```

In result you hide this system launcher (sys app) from list of launchers when you have a few launchers

Answer (score 1):

Simple command to remove any app from the device, try this:

```
 pm uninstall --user 0
```

This command will forcefully remove that app from the device.

Comment: Forcefully uninstalled pre installed app using super user command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an rooted android device then you can easily uninstall pre-installed apps from your device. My OnePlus device is rooted with Magisk manager.

Rooting an Android device gives you admin privileges towards your device and so you can easily install or uninstall any system application.

However, command line method also works most of the time. I have tested adb method on MIUI device for removing bloatware.

You can follow [stackover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898846)[flow](https://onegyd.com/debloat-miui-remove-bloatwares/) [read this thread....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898846)

ADB command: `pm uninstall -k <package_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the adb command:

```
adb uninstall <package-name>
```

make sure your device is connected