# Xamarin.Forms (Droid) Attempt to re-install MyProject.Android without first uninstalling

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I hadn't had problems deploying my app on my smartphone but when I uninstalled it from my phone and try to deploy it again I found this error.

**Error:**

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install MyProject.Android without first uninstalling.]

Surely I'm missing something so I'd appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: You might need to uninstall it manually using adb. Have at look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556750/how-to-uninstall-an-android-app-from-command-line-on-the-device

Comment: Try go into the settings, find some section that has to do with apps and make sure it isn't on there. Some flavors of Android do not uninstall the full app by just deleting the icon

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis , it works for me. I went to **Settings - Aps - MyProject.Android - Menu on the top at the right - Uninstall for all users - Accept** and I was able to deploying my app again. Thanks so much.

Comment: Upgraded it to an answer for you to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try go into the settings for your device/emulator, find some section that has to do with apps and make sure it isn't on there anymore.

Some flavors of Android do not uninstall the full app by just deleting the icon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a installation hidden in the phone second profile, visual studio installed the App in both profiles.

The solution was uninstall the App manually in both profiles.