# How do you uninstall an APK file in the Android emulator using adb command

Tags: android, adb

How do you uninstall an APK file in the Android emulator using **adb command**

Answer (score 1):

Use this comment

> Before doing this you have to connect your emulator, using this adb
>   comments for connect  **adb connect your_ipaddress**

```
pm uninstall -k <package_name>
```

**(or)**

```
adb shell pm uninstall *your.package.name*
```

Please check doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm

Comment: thnaks @Gowthaman M

Comment: @HiteshVijayvargiya you are welocme..if my answer is usefull please donot forgot to accept..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

where `<package_name>` is full package name of your application that you want to uninstall.
for example : `adb uninstall com.shashi.myApp`

Comment: I am getting this error Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Comment: thanks shashi patel it worekd

Comment: How did you get it to work? i am also getting that delet failed internal error